# Excel formula for checking if a string is a substring of another string and if so, creating a hyperlink

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So I've been working on this problem at my office now for awhile.  I have an excel file with a few thousand lines representing files that the office has either opened, scanned in, closed or destroyed.  I need to hyperlink each line where a file has been scanned in to the scanned file.  I was able to extra all of the hyperlinks, I just need to see if they match.  Here is an example:

```
__________________________________________________________________________
  |     A   |     B        |  C   |                     D
---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
1 | 05RE045 | Smith, Jones | Case | /server/2001/01CG938 Smith, Jones File 
2 | 05WT852 | Smith, Jones | Case | /server/1998/98CG123 Smith, Jones Case 
3 | 91BK394 | Smith, Jones | Case | /server/1994/94BK984 Smith, Jones Case 
4 | 01CG938 | Smith, Jones | File | /server/1984/89M540 Smith, Jones Case 
5 | 89CG034 | Smith, Jones | Case | /server/2001/01WT574 Smith, Jones Case
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm trying to make it so that if text from column "A" appears in column "D" (as it is the only consistently used naming feature), then columns A, B and C will keep their same text, but also hyperlink to the appropriate address in Column D (with the understanding that column "D" will not always match up with column "A").  In this case, line 1 at column D matches with line 4, columnbs A, B and C.

I tried writing a java program that would create an excel file based upon some regular expressions parsing the folder name, but I'm hitting brick walls and am having trouble justifying spending the amount of time I am writing a program as a law clerk at a law firm.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: This would require VBA, not a formula if you want to alter B,C and D

Comment: Hmmmm, alright.  Didn't realize that would be the case.  Thank you.

Comment: Instead of altering things (a hard'ish problem), how about simply highlighting any inconsistencies as this is an easy problem? Then you could simply visually scan through for any issues.

Comment: If I understand the problem, is it true that in your example, none of the five records match?  If so, you might want to add another record where it does just for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

As @Raystafarian said, the problem can't be solved precisely as described without VBA.

However, it can be worked around to give the same kind of results. It doesn't sound like it should be much more complicated than using the `HYPERLINK` function, though it depends on what sort of solution is acceptable.

I would suggest adding a fifth column for your links, with the following formula:

```
=IF(ISERR(FIND($A1,$D1)),"No Link",HYPERLINK(LEFT($D1,FIND(" ",$D1)),"Link"))
```

You will probably have to add something just ahead of the `LEFT` to complete the rest of the folder path, but I don't know your filing structure.

Similarly, you could achieve something more similar to your original aim by hiding your original three columns and add three duplicates which use formulae like the one described above to give hyperlinks as appropriate